# Powershell Regex extracting values not ending with mid string

Tags: regex, powershell

I need a regex, that will work with powershell.

It needs to take a string like

```
..\..\..\packages\Microsoft.Samples.Security.SSPI.1.0.0\lib\net11\Microsoft.Samples.Security.SSPI.dll
..\..\..\packages\Antlr3.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll
```

Extracting the verion number and the name. In these cases:

```
Samples.Security.SSPI and 1.0.0
Antlr3 and 3.4.1.9004
```

I believed

```
packages\\(?<name>[^\\\\]+(?!<!\.[0-9]+\.))\.(?<version>[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+)[\\\/]
```

should do the trick

But it doesn’t seem to in a windows power shell. The lookback doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with powershell's regex flavor, but it seems you don't need the look behind to begin with.

You can use a lazy quantifier `+?` to stop at the first occurrence instead:

```
packages\\(?<name>[^\\]+?)\.(?<version>\d+(?:\.\d+)*)
```

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/uQ0rK2/1).